# PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I got an above error when place an order with other than *base currency*. My store base currency is **USD**.If i place an order with "**GBP**" or "**INR**" or else currency, I got an error like

**PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).**

I have searched google. Most of the forum said, it may be a *rounding issue*! But it was working well still now.Today only i got an error like this. And also they got an error with all currency. But for me its only showing other than *base currency*

**EDIT:**

```
[ITEMAMT] => 239.00 
[TAXAMT] => 0.00 
[SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
[L_NUMBER0] => 8sa-N7407
[L_NAME0] => Pink & Gold Velvet, Net Party Wear Sarees
[L_QTY0] => 1 
[L_AMT0] => 239.00 )
```

Request result from checkout page

Anybody have an idea to uplift me from this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: may i know your base currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put a wrong condition on my custom module. So it called core files. So only it didn't work other than base currency

```
if(Mage::helper('paypalmulticurrency')->isActive()){

        return parent::_render();

    }
```

From above if condition, I set if its being active, call parent method. But I want like,
If it isn't being active only, call parent method. Just changed the if condition, its working well now!

```
if(!Mage::helper('paypalmulticurrency')->isActive()){

        return parent::_render();

    }
```